# CMD Script - cannot set variable within FIND

Tags: string, batch-file, variables, cmd

1. I use an external program to generate a string
2. I need to find out if the string has the word "not" in it
3. If so, I set a certain variable to use later.

1 and 2 work without problems, but I cannot get 3 to work.

My code:

```
SET EXE="path\to\program.exe"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('%EXE% argument') do (
rem echo %%i
set mystatus=%%i
)

echo %mystatus%
```

^ works up to here ^ - `echo` returns the correct value. Now I want to return a simpler value that tells me if the string "not" was present in `%mystatus%` var

```
set "isNot="

ECHO.%mystatus%| FIND /I "not">Nul && ( 
  Echo.Found "not"
  do something
  rem ^this works^
  set isNot= "true"
) || (
  Echo.Did not find "not"
  do something
  rem ^this works^
  set isNot= "false"
)
```

now, out of FIND, this returns nothing: WHY?

```
echo %isNot%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your answer - let's say, naïve.

First, I can't reproduce your result. It worked perfectly for me, returning `isnot` set to  **<kbd>Space</kbd>"false"** or **<kbd>Space</kbd>"true"**, not `nothing`.

Had `isnot` been undefined, then the `echo` response should have been `Echo is off`, so `isnot` *was* defined in your test. I would use `echo +%isNot%+` for this test so that the string is shown with an obvious delimiter. If it contained just spaces - well, they tend to be remarkably invisible.

As to the solution, I's suggest

```
set "isnot="
if "%mystatus%" neq "%mystatus:not=%" set "isnot=Y"
```

which avoids `find` and piping and conditions, setting `isnot` to be either `defined` or `not defined` as appropriate, ready for testing using

```
if defined isnot (echo not was not found) else (echo not was found)
```

The reason for this is that `if defined` works on the *run-time* status of the variable, hence it can be used within a `code block` where the variable may be switched from one status to the other.

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign a terminal `\`, <kbd>Space</kbd> or `"` - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.

Comment: I think OP's result of `%IsNot%` is because he tried to `echo` it inside of the code block and no `delayedexpansion` exists, hence the result differences you've found.

Comment: @Gerhard : Agreed. `out of FIND` might indicate that - but we can only deal with the posted code - the permutations and combinations of speculation are endless...

Comment: Yes, just an indication of why I think the results differ. The OP's posted issue and resolution is in fact not related then. :)

Comment: Sorry for the naivety. I am not an expert. I did tried a variation of if-neq before for this script, but somehow it didn't work. Yours works, except I had to add a percentage sign after %mystatus. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @Gherard I did tried adding delayedexpansion in an eariler version of the script but echoeing the variable still returned nothing. not space-true, not true, nothing. don't know why.

Comment: OK - `%` inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Idiotic mistake, it seems.
There should not be spaces after `=` when setting a variable.
Removed the spaces, and it work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a guess as to your intended task, but my assumption is that you are trying to determine if the executable command returns the string, `'path\to\program.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

If that is the case, then perhaps this would be a better overall solution for you:

```sh
@Set "exe=path\to\program.exe"
@For %%G In ("%exe%")Do @If "%%~aG" Lss "-" (Echo ERROR: No such object '%exe%')Else If "%%~aG" GEq "d" (Echo ERROR: '%exe%' is a directory object.)Else %%G argument
```

*All you would need to change is the path on line **1**, and the string `argument` at the end of line **2**.*